# Batch loading binary files

Tags: binary, large-files, hexl-mode

I just discovered [`vlf-mode` (View Large Files)](http://github.com/m00natic/vlfi) and I am using it to view a large binary file in `hexl-mode` and read certain metadata from headers within the file.  It works great, with one exception. When I move to another "batch" within the file, hexl-mode starts the addresses of the next batch at `0x00000000` which makes it hard to know which byte I am actually at.

Are there existing solutions for viewing large binary files but maintaining information about the absolute "address" of a given line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sounds like a missing feature in `vlf-mode`, and quite possibly some missing customization in `hexl-mode`.

The way `hexl-mode` works if by running the `hexl` program (shipped with Emacs, see `hexl-program`), and displaying the output. This output already contains the offsets, they're just made non-editable. So, `vlf-mode` should add `vlf-start-pos` to all of those. Then of course, things like `hexl-goto-address` should also be modified, by transparently substracting the same `vls-start-pos`.
It might also be worth forcing `vlf-batch-size` to be alignment friendly by making it a multiple of 256 when `hexl-mode` is used.

That sounds like a too invasive change to do it here, but I suspect the `vlf-mode` author would appreciate the feedback, and would be in a good position to implement just that.